# Adding ChartPanel from JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am trying to visualize some data using JFreeChart. I have created a `JFrame` using drag and drop in Netbean IDE. Apart from other component, I have added an empty `JPanel`, which will hold `ChartPanel`. I access some data, using other components, and using that data I wanted to create `ChartPanel` and add it to `JPanel`. The action is performed when I click a button. However, the `ChartPanel` is not shown. Can someone point out what I am missing?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart( "plotTitle",
        "xaxis label", "yaxis label", dataset, false, false, false);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    jPanel1.add(chartPanel);
    this.pack();
    jPanel1.revalidate();
    this.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: What layout manager is `jPanel1` using?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Netbean set the layout in generated code, which is GroupLayout.

Comment: The code is very big and I thought it will be enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: 1- Change the layout manager to `BorderLayout`; 2- A "runnable example" is not a code dump, but a short, self contained, compilable example of your work flow which demonstrates your problem